# Display Photo from UIImageView in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I got a class, which holds the info for tableView

```
    @interface Tricks : NSObject

   @property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *trickPhoto;
   @property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *trickName;
   @property(nonatomic) BOOL landed;

   +(NSMutableArray *)trickList;
```

@end

In this class, when I hit save it creates a cell in tableview

```
-(IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender

    Tricks *trick = [[Tricks alloc]init];
        trick.trickName = self.trickLabel.text;
        trick.trickPhoto.image = self.trickPhotoTake.image;
        [[Tricks trickList]addObject:trick];
```

And in detailViewController pushed from tableViewCell I want to display name of the trick and photo, but it only display the name.
Using the breakpoint I know, there is value in UIImage property called trickPhoto, but no picture on display.
Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards, you need to use:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

The any property only exists in the class it is created in.  If you are in ViewControllr and setting DetailViewController's UIImageView property with image named @"image.png", then that property of DetailViewController only exists in ViewController.

Try:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue    
 *)segue sender:(id)sender
if ([segue.destinationViewController        
 isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]) {
    viewController = 
     segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([segue.identifier 
isEqualToString:@"____enterSegueIdentifier____"])
{
        detailViewController.trickPhoto.image = 
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"______"];
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: detailViewController.trickPhoto.image = trick.trickPhoto.image;
picture is only in the view, from where i want load it

Answer (score 0):

In the detailViewController you can call the extern property from the other viewController like this:

```
  extern UIImageView *trickPhoto;
```

Put the below code after the imports.

```
      @interface detailViewController ()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think `extern` is needed on this?